# C Program - Output a specific line from a file based on user input

Tags: c, file

I would like to output specific a line and strings from a file based on user input.

The user input is as follows:

```
while (1) {
    printf("Card number: ");
    scanf("%d", &cardNum);

    printf("PIN: ");
    scanf("%d", &pin);

    if (cardNum == 1 && pin == 2 || cardNum == 3 && pin == 4) {
        break;
    }
    printf("Error! Card number or PIN is invalid.\n");
}
```

The text file is formatted like so:

```
1, 2, 1000, 100
3, 4, 1500, 50
```

where the first number is the card number, the second is the pin, the third is the balance and the fourth is their overdraft. Each line represents a different account/user.

My guess would be to get the card number and pin and check each line in the file to see if the first and second numbers match up to the ones given by the user.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "*My guess would be to...*". Sounds reasonable. So why don't you try it? What specific problem or missing knowledge is blocking you? That is, in addition to describing the task you need to describe one specific issue you have that you would like answered here. Does it help to know that you can use `fgets` to read a line from file, `strtok` to extract each field and `atoi` to convert from string to integer?

Comment: instead of strtok or atoi, you could also use `sscanf`, which makes this even simpler.

Comment: Here is a version with fscanf: https://onlinegdb.com/FOY0JD1Be

Comment: Using `fgets()` to read lines and a non-destructive parser (`sscanf()` possibly — not `strtok()` because it is destructive) to check whether the lines match.  You could probably simply format the entered card number and PIN as they would be found in the file (including both trailing commas), and use `strncmp()` carefully to determine whether the start of the input line matches the wanted values.  Using a non-destructive parser means echoing the desired output line is easier — it hasn't been damaged while you were looking at it.

Comment: Also note that ultimately, using command line arguments to specify the file name and the card number and PIN might be preferable to having the program prompt for input.  That will make testing easier.  However, it may be out of bounds for your current task and/or experience and knowledge.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thank you so much, this helped a ton.